# How can we add custom column in control panel for any channel entry

Tags: channel-entries, control-panel

How can we add custom column in control panel (EE verstion 2.9.2) content >> Edit for any channel entry?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want a whole lot more control over column display in the channel > edit area, you should look at the add-on [Zenbu](https://zenbustudio.com/software/zenbu). It will allow you to customize the way channel entry content is displayed in the control panel, per channel, and per member group.

(If on the other hand you need to display some content that isn't in the channel entries in a column, I don't have a quick answer for you!)